# Heroes Chronicles in HD resolution

Tags: technical-issues, gog, heroes-of-might-and-magic-3, heroes-chronicles

I have bought Heroes Chronicles Pack on GOG.com, which includes all 8 chapters of this game. Unfortunately, the game works only on 4:3 resolutions and I am not able to run it on HD mode.

I found some information on the web, that it is possible to play Heroes Chronicles, but this solution seems like a workaround which is not satisfying for me - it requires installed Heores 3 Complete Edition HD and then I will have to import campaigns from Heroes Chronicles as maps with scenarios.

Is it really the only way to enjoy playing this game in HD resolution, or maybe there is some other way to run Chronicles standalone with modern resolution?

As I said before - I am looking for some solution that would work properly on the GOG version.